# What mathematics is helpful for studying $\int_{|\mathbf{x}|<R} d^n \mathbf x \frac{e^{i \mathbf k\cdot \mathbf x}}{|\mathbf x|^2+a^2}$?

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

The integral in the question
$$\int_{|\mathbf{x}|<R} d^n \mathbf x \frac{e^{i \mathbf k\cdot \mathbf x}}{|\mathbf x|^2+a^2}$$
arises quite many times when I study physics. ($a, R, \mathbf k$ are constants. I am especially interested in the asymptotic behavior of the integral as $R \to \infty$ or $a \to 0$ with fixed $\mathbf k$.) Since this integral is highly oscillatory, it seems hard to estimate the integral.

I have heard that harmonic analysis deals with the Fourier transform, so it might be related to this integral. What mathematics do I need to study to better understand the above integral? (I have a relatively strong background in mathematics. I know Lebesgue integration and basic functional analysis.)

Comment: What do you mean by asymptotic behaviour of the integral ? You want to compute the limit explicitely (if it exists) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing to hyperspherical coordinates gives
$$I(R, a) = \int_{x < R}
 \frac {e^{i \boldsymbol k \cdot \boldsymbol x}} {x^2 + a^2} d\boldsymbol x =
S_{n - 2} \int_0^R \int_0^\pi
 \frac {e^{i k r \cos \theta}} {r^2 + a^2} r^{n - 1} \sin^{n - 2} \theta \,
 d\theta dr = \\
(2 \pi)^{n/2} k^{1 - n/2} \int_0^R
 \frac {r^{n/2}} {r^2 + a^2} J_{n/2 - 1}(k r) dr.$$
If $n \geq 3$, the asymptotic behavior for small $a$ is just given by the corresponding limit:
$$\lim_{a \to 0} I(R, a) = I(R, 0) = \frac
  {\pi^{n/2} R^{\hspace {01px} n - 2}}
  {\left( \frac n 2 - 1 \right) \Gamma {\left( \frac n 2 \right)}}
 \hspace {1px} {_1 \hspace {-1.5px} F_2}
  {\left( \frac n 2 - 1; \frac n 2, \frac n 2; -\frac {(k R)^2} 4 \right)}.$$
For $r \to \infty$,
$$\frac {r^{n/2}} {r^2 + a^2} J_{n/2 - 1}(k r) =
-\sqrt {\frac 2 {\pi k}} \, r^{(n - 5)/2}
  \sin \left( k r - \frac {\pi (n + 1)} 4 \right) +
 o(r^{(n - 5)/2}).$$
If $n \geq 6$, it appears that the integral of the remainder term is $o(R^{(n - 5)/2})$ (I haven't proved this rigorously). Applying integration by parts to the leading term gives
$$I(R, a) =
\frac 1 \pi \left( \frac {2 \pi} k \right)^{(n + 1)/2} R^{(n - 5)/2}
  \cos \left( k R - \frac {\pi (n + 1)} 4 \right) +
 o(R^{(n - 5)/2})$$
for $R \to \infty$.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot! That behavior was actually what I expected. It is also surprising that this can be done in a relatively elementary method, yet one has to be familiar with special functions.